# Keeping Hibernate Collections in Memory

Tags: java, hibernate

I am running into a problem managing my Hibernate-backed collections.  The problem is illustrated in the code below; briefly,

1. A single session and transaction are started.
2. All instances of ClassA are loaded and walked to force Hibernate to load all instances of ClassC.  At this point all instances of ClassC actually load via lazy fetching.
3. In the same transaction and session, all instances of ClassB are loaded.
4. All instances of ClassC are no longer available (the containing collections are empty) and do not lazy load if requested.

What's the best way to load up the data sets needed and keep them in memory?

**Notes**:

The project is in rapid-prototyping mode so I am using a single session and single 
transaction to load up two big chunks of the application's data. This is also a desktop application so the use of a single session and transaction may not even be a problem in the long run if the code were working.

I set up ehcache and the debugger showing that Hibernate found the ehcache config file.  The cache is set such that

```
maxElementsInMemory="5000000"
eternal="true"
```

the timeouts are set to 20 mins, even though eternal is set true, just to be sure the session isn't timing out.

The data set size is not particularly large, about 100k records.
The Hibernate 3.0 module packaged with NetBeans was use to create the class templates from a data model.

---

**The mapping file looks roughly like this:**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class catalog="myCatalog" name="ClassA" table="classA">
    <id ... </id>
    <set inverse="true" name="classCs" sort="natural">
      <key>
        <column length="12" name="mykey" not-null="true"/>
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="ClassC"/>
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Class definitions:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "classA", catalog = "myCatalog")
public class ClassA implements java.io.Serializable {
   private SortedSet<ClassC> classCs = new TreeSet<ClassC>();

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "ClassA")
   public SortedSet<ClassC> getClassCs() {
      return this.classCs;
   }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "classB", catalog = "myCatalog")
public class ClassB implements java.io.Serializable {
    // ... It is possible to walk collections in this class to reach some instances of classA.
}

public class ClassC implements java.io.Serializable {
    // ... contains no collections
}
```

**Manifestation of problem:**

```
// in Hibernate Util   
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Application.tx = session.beginTransaction();

    // Load data set 'A' and force collections to load
    List<ClassA> listClassA = new ArrayList<ClassA>();
    Query q = Application.session.createQuery("from ClassA as a").setReadOnly(true);
    Iterator<ClassA> iterator = q.list().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        ClassA ca = (ClassA)iterator.next();
        // force member collection to load -- at present this is necessary even though FetchType is EAGER
        ca.getClassCs(); 
        listClassA.add(ca);
    }           

    // The collections of classCs are in are in memory here
    for(ClassA a : listClassA){
        log.info(a.getId() + "-" + a.getClassCs().size());
    } 

    // Load data set 'B'
    List<ClassB> listClassB = new ArrayList<ClassB>();
    String sq = "from classB as b where ...";
    Query q = Application.session.createQuery(sq);
    listClassB.addAll(q.list());

    // The collections of classCs are NOT in memory and touching collections does not force reload
    // The collections exist but now all have size zero
    for(ClassA a : listClassA){
        log.info(a.getId() + "-" + a.getClassCs().size());
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?  How do you know classCs are not in memory?  Do you try something like ca.getClassCs().iterator.next() and get a LazyInitializerException?  Since everything is in one transaction it shouldn't matter if you're using eager or lazy, you should be able to access the entity.

Comment: @Pace For each classA I write getclassCs().size() to standard out.  In the first pass the sizes are correctly reported but in the second the sizes are all zero.  I don't get a LazyInitializerException though, at least not that I can see.

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me.  It probably doesn't have anything to do with eager vs. lazy since you should get the correct size or a LazyInitializerException.  It also probably doesn't have anything to do with the secondary cache since everything is in one transaction you'll only be using the session-cache.  My best guess at the moment is some kind of object corruption.

Comment: Please show the code where you access the List<ClassA> a second time that shows that the ClassC properties are no longer mapped. Is there other code not shown, where you interact with your (global, yikes) Session object?

Comment: @matt-b I added the code used to show that ClassCs are no longer mapped. This is the only code executed other than some swing boiler plate.  I agree the global session is a bit scary, I'll do something about that.

Comment: @Pace Thanks for narrowing the problem down.  When you say object corruption, does that generally mean that there is something wrong with the mappings?  Is it possible to configure the session cache?

Comment: Is this the only code running? Could another thread be running code that somehow touches instances of `A` or `C`?

Comment: @matt-b I isolated the code on a single thread (now shown above) and still see the problem.

Comment: By "object corruption" I believe Pace was referring to code inside your entity classes (or other code) removing the C elements from A on their own - i.e. if getClassC() also did something silly like call .clear()

Comment: I was thinking more of a bidirectional association problem since that is where many people trip up.  From the above code I can't see where anything would go wrong.  What does a.getClassCs() look like?

Comment: Nevermind, just realized you posted getClassCs() and it looks fine.  So lets focus on the eager loading not working.  What happens if you remove ca.getclassCs() from your loop?  Is the size 0 both times?

Comment: Looking at the trace  I see no errors and what appears to be an automatic flush of the session cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turns out that Hibernate can optionally flush the session cache before each query.  One of the settings to control the session cache is session.setFlushMode().  In Hibernate 3.2.5, setting flush mode to:

```
FlushMode.COMMIT or FlushMode.MANUAL
```

achieves the desired result.  I found this while reading "Hibernate in Action".